# Xcode: Signing says "No accounts found", but Accounts says it exists

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I am a Windows user trying to sign an iOS app - first for testing, later on I will have to sign for release into the app store. As always, I am stuck somewhere.

What I try:
I open the *.xcodeproj file in Xcode, go to General -> Signing, and it tells me

> No accounts found
>   Add a developer account to sign your app
>   [ Add account... ]

So I click on the button, and it opens the "Accounts" window, and opens the dialog

> Sign in to Xcode with your Apple ID
>   Sign in to Xcode with your Apple ID. Don't have an Apple ID? You can create one for free.
>   Apple ID Password (forgot Password)
>   [______] [______]
>   [ Create Apple ID ] [ Cancel ] [ Sign In ]

In the window behind it, an Apple ID is already visible. My Apple ID.

But of course I can enter it again. Or not, ouch:

> Account already exists.
>   This account has already been added
>   [ OK ]

Also, I cannot drag the account from the accounts window into the signing window, let alone use the context menu.

How can I get that already added account into "Signing"?

Answer (score 25):

If you are getting: "there are no accounts registered with xcode. add your developer account" then you you can go to you can go to `Xcode -> preferences -> Accounts` then add your account with the `+` sign.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this process with **Fastlane**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, not sure, sorry.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You should maybe add that as a question.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. These steps helped for me:

- On https://developer.apple.com/account choose "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
- In Identifiers group on left side choose "App IDs"
- Add App ID with bundle ID matching the one from project's Bundle Identifier

After that I also restarted Xcode. Now I can choose the team as it should be.

Comment: My problem was similar - my bundle ID didn't match those in the App ID list.

Answer (score 6):

I also had this issue, and the fix was simply to restart Xcode.